# refresh only the divs of the page issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have one page (index.php) which is separated in sections (divs). I like when i click on link to refresh the particular div but my problem is that the value is not send via url (with get method) to next page (in manage_team_teacher2.php for example). The id of div for example is item4_section10.

here's the link

```
<a class="nav-link" href="manage_team_teacher2.php?id_team=<?= $row['id_team'];?>">manage</a>
```

here's jquery code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
     $('.nav-link').click( function() {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#item4_section10').load(href, function() {

        });
        return false; 
     });
 });
</script>
```

thanx a lot

Comment: Can you check in the console what is the real URL you are getting the section from and the response? at first glance this seems all right.

Comment: the problem is tha the basic page is index.php.. if i put to url index.php it load in div whole the page! i like to show me in div only the page manage_team_teacher2.php with the get value. in console show me that the value is send but in url i see http://localhost/diplomatiki/index3.php

Answer (score 0):

You can create a link and iFrame combination for this. You can use the following HTML

```
<a href="manage_team_teacher2.php?id_team=<?= $row['id_team'];?>" id="RefreshButton" target="DataFrame">Refresh</a>
<iframe id="DataFrame" name="DataFrame" src="" width="200px" height="200px" frameborder="0">
        <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```

And use the following jQuery to refresh that on link click

```
$(function () {
    $("#RefreshButton").click(function () {
        var href = $("#RefreshButton").attr('href');
        $("#DataFrame").attr('src', ''); //
        $("#DataFrame").attr('src', '/* Mention the atrget url here */');
        return false;
    });
}
```

Comment: my href href="manage_team_teacher2.php?id_team=<?= $row['id_team'];?> has value from database.. i cant put it directly to $("#DataFrame").attr('src', '/* Mention the atrget url here */');

Comment: i have this problem and i need your advice.. my page is index.php wich have a lot of divs.. page manage_team_teacher2.php dont take the get value because url stay the same (localhost/index.php)

Comment: if i create a link like this: http://localhost/project/index.php?category=manage_team_teacher2.php&id_team=<?= $row['id_team'];?> (take the page name with get method (category)) show me in div the entire page!!!

Comment: if we pass the id_team value with jquery?? how we can do that?

Comment: In the onload method of manage_team_teacher2.php page, you can write the code to hide all content other than the div mentioned in the URL.